# I have an issue with removing an object key with a for in loop

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I'm using a for x in loop to check if a value is == to [] and if so remove the property using remove but it just does not seem to work.

```
const whosOnline = (a) => {

var obj = { online:[],
offline:[],
away:[] };



for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
if(a[i].lastActivity > 10 && a[i].status == 'online'){obj.away.push(a[i].username)}
else if(a[i].status == 'offline'){obj.offline.push(a[i].username)}
else{obj.online.push(a[i].username)}
  }
  for(let x in obj){
  console.log(obj[x])
   if(obj[x] === []){delete obj[x]}}
  return obj
    }
```

Comment: you are comparing different objects even if they both are empty arrays. try checking if the array is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were close, however you also need to reference the array index for each object key value. Comments explaining this in the code below.

```
var obj = { online:[],
offline:[],
away:[] };

for(var x in obj){
    if(!obj[x][0]){ // The 0 is the index inside the online array, next loop it will be the offline array and then the away array.
        console.log('The array is empty');
        // Do what you want to do now that it is empty
        // This will continue to loop through and check the value of all the keys in the object.
    }
}
console.log('done');
```

Good luck -
Mitch from
https://spangle.com.au

Comment: Fantastic thanks guys, I was completely stumpef. It's weird because if I call object[x] I get [] so I thought if I use an if statement to the same effect it would return true. But now I know I have to reference the array index also.

Answer (score 0):

Using some debugging (simply testing if a console.log gets printed for instance) you find that your if-condition is never true.

This is because you test if an array equals a newly created empty array. This can never be the case, because objects are compared by object reference instead of value.

Instead you want to probably test to see if your array is empty by doing ‘if(obj[x].length===0)’ (or shorter: ‘if(!obj[x].length)’)